# Visual Studio 2008 assembly level debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In the **Disassembly window**, I have something like:

```
   call        dword ptr ds:[6275FCh]
```

What can I type in the address box, in order to go to the indirect address pointed to by [6275FCh], without having to copy-paste it from the **Memory window**, and of course without tracing into the thing?

EDIT: Actually the ultimate dream would be to resolve the address directly to a symbol, but I doubt that is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally solved this a few weeks ago. So I figured, why not share?

The thing is that even the address field in the debugger's disassembly and memory windows are "type-aware"

And the type of 6275FCh (or 0x6275FC) is void*. Thus the data pointed to by that constant is meaningless. In order to give it a meaning we must cast it to a useful type. Consequently the answer to my question above is, type this into the address box:

```
 *(int*)0x006275FC // *(int*)006275FCh works as well
```

And another nifty example is, to type this into the address field:

```
 *((int*)ESP + 1)
```

The memory window will always show the buffer pointed to by **the second element on the stack!**

[32-bit-ints assumed above]